# Where is the position number at

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a chess board strategy application in WinForms c#.
Someone from here was gracious enough to help with this code.
When it is run, it does everything I wanted except that the `sq.position` values are wrong.
The value like `A1` should be `A7`, `A6` should be `A2`

How can I reverse the order of the number value in this code:

```
private void Test_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int blockSize = 70;
    Panel[,] chessBoardPanels = new Panel[8, 8];

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j > 8; j++)
        {
            ChessSquare sq = new ChessSquare(((char)(65 + i)).ToString(), j);
            sq.Color = (i + (j % 2)) % 2 == 0 ? Color.Black : Color.White;

            Panel p = new Panel()
            {
                Size = new Size(blockSize, blockSize),
                BackColor = sq.Color,
                Tag = sq,
                Location = new Point(blockSize * i + 15, blockSize * j + 15)
            };
            p.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(squareMouseEnter);
            p.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(squareMouseLeave);

            chessBoardPanels[i, j] = p;
            groupBox1.Controls.Add(p);
        }
    }
}

private void squareMouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel p = (Panel)sender;
    ChessSquare sq = (ChessSquare)p.Tag;
    p.BackColor = sq.Color;
}

private void squareMouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel p = (Panel)sender;
    ChessSquare sq = (ChessSquare)p.Tag;
    p.BackColor = Color.Aqua;
    label1.Text = string.Format("Current position: {0}", sq.Position);
}

public class ChessSquare
{
    public string Letter { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; }

    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public string Position
    {
        get { return string.Format("{0}{1}", Letter, Number + 1); }
    }

    public ChessSquare()
    { }

    public ChessSquare(string letter, int number)
    {
        Letter = letter;
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

I am still very new to this type of programming....

Comment: for (int j = 0; j > 8; j++)  j never been greater than 8

Comment: Sorry my bad.  Didn't see that error in code....I tried changing the value of j but it didn't work

Comment: A better place to ask questions of this nature is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. It will probably get closed as off-topic here.

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge - no, there definitely is a problem in the code so that's OK for SO.

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
ChessSquare sq = new ChessSquare(((char)(65 + i)).ToString(), j);
```

to that:

```
ChessSquare sq = new ChessSquare(((char)(65 + i)).ToString(), 7 - j);
```

Update: Corrected! Thanks user2772713!

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert..But just in case anyone else has the same problem the correct value is 7 instead of 9